# What does $* mean in a make command?

Tags: gnu-make

There's a command in a batch file that I didn't write that reads:

```
make -f foo_mk $*
```

Printing * using the echo command gives me a list of the files in that folder i.e foo1_mk and foo1.mk. Calling the command does not appear to give the same output as though I called:

```
make -f foo1_mk $foo1_mk
make -f foo1_mk $foo1.mk
```

So what does $* mean in this context?

Comment: Let's see the "batch file".

Comment: It means what the documentation says it does.

Answer (score 1):

### For GNU Makefiles

The body of a rule in a makefile has access to special variables, including `$*` which expands to the stem with which the pattern of the rule matches.

You can find a list of these automatic variables in the [GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables-1)

Comment: She says "in a batch file", not "in a makefile".

Comment: correct, the tags on the other hand indicate that this question is about makefiles so I assume she called it `batch file` by mistake

Comment: It's a .bat file that calls make -f foo1_mk $* where foo1_mk is a makefile

Comment: Then I'd refer to ssfang's answer. However, I would expect the line to read `make -f foo1_mk "$*"` with `$*` being in quotes. As Mike says, it would help to see this in context.

Comment: I can call make -f foo1_mk $* directly from the command line and get the same output.

Comment: Yes, and I just did some reading up on ssfang's resources myself, without the double quotes, `$*` will expand to the positional parameters and `"$*` expands to all positional parameters in one string. Have a look at ssfang's second link